# tflearn DNN model gives TargetsData/Y:0 error

Tags: python-3.x, csv, machine-learning, tensorflow, tflearn

I get the following error...

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (16,) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 16)'

I understand that this has to do with the shape of my `Y` variable which in this case is the variable `labels`, but I'm not sure how to change the shape to make my model work.

Basically, I have a `CSV` file which I saved into a variable using `pandas`...

```
data = pd.read_csv('Speed Dating Data.csv')
```

After some preprocessing, I decided to extract my target class as so...

```
# Target label used for training
labels = np.array(data["age"], dtype=np.float32)
```

Next I removed this column from my `data` variable...

```
# Data for training minus the target label.
data = np.array(data.drop("age", axis=1), dtype=np.float32)
```

Then I decided to setup my model...

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 32])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 16, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model.
model = tflearn.DNN(net)

model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)
```

If I run this, I get the error above. Since my `labels` seems to be `(16,)` but I need it to be `(?, 16)`, I tried the following code...

```
labels = labels[np.newaxis, :]
```

But this gives yet another error. I think I am unsure as to what form my target class, `labels`, is supposed to be. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape your **label** according to follows,

```
label= np.reshape(label,(-1,16)) # since you have 16 classes
```

which reshape the **label** to (?,16).

Hope this helps.

**Updated according to your Requirement.** And added comments to changes.

```
labels = np.array(data["age"], dtype=np.float32)
label= np.reshape(label,(-1,1)) #reshape to [6605,1]

data = np.array(data.drop("age", axis=1), dtype=np.float32)

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 32])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='softmax') #Since this is a regression problem only one output
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model.
model = tflearn.DNN(net)

model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)
```

Comment: This solved that issue, but now I have another one. `ValueError: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 16 but is 6605 for 'Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [6605], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [?,16].`

Comment: So my `labels` are not divisible by 16 apparently, I did not think it would have to be. Is there any quick fix to this?

Comment: Can u post the shape of both label and data ?

Comment: Since your label data is age, I believe you are doing a regression problem, not classification?

Comment: Yes the shape for `labels` is `(6605,)` and the shape for `data` is `(6605, 32)`

Comment: And yes this is a regression problem, I am trying to predict age based on on the `data` feature set.

Comment: I updated my answer, Since its a regression problem your output of the model should be 1. Pls use the updated code